# const_iterator over referenced list of pointers

Tags: c++, class, object, reference, const-iterator

There is a thing I really can't understand. Following Situation:

Test.h file:

```
class Test{
    public:
        const std::list<Item*>& getItems() { return m_items; }
        void showSomething() const;
    private:
        std::list<Item*> m_items;
}
```

Test.cpp file:

```
void Test::showSomething() const{
    for (std::list<Item*>::const_iterator item_it = getItems().begin(); item_it != getPlayers().end(); item_it++) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio tells me, that this doesn't work and underlines getItems() in the for loop. The error translates something like "type qualifier is not compatible with member function getItems ... the Object is const Test".

I know that getItems() returns a const reference to the list of Item-Pointers. But why can't I use it in the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `const`.

Try this:

```
const std::list<Item*>& getItems() const { return m_items; }
```

You need const, because `showSomething` method, from which `getItems` is called is const.

Comment: @Jejo: nope, there's overload of `begin()` and `end()` with const. See this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin

Comment: Wow this is strange. So the first const is for the return value and the second because the function mustn't change the object? I tried it and it works ... thank you!